# Which is easier to configure Replication for: MySql 5.5 CE vs SQL Server 2008r2 Express?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

As the question states, which server is easiest to setup replication for?

My needs are:

A local master and a remote (VPN connected) slave.

I am no where near expert in either database so which would be the easiest to configure and maintain? Also what literature would be recommended to ensure success in either database?

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why this was downvoted?

Comment: You're effectively asking `"What should I eat for dinner? Pasta or fish tacos?"` They're two completely different things. We have no idea what your application needs are, what method you need for replication. Sync or Async. etc etc.

Comment: @MDMarra Aside from the fact that Pasta wins, I am looking for an honest opinion based upon the communities experience. I understand the inherent risks of a flame war, however I need to come to a decision and I felt this is the best resource to use in reaching that decision.

Comment: If you read the [faq], questions that ask for opinion, polling, or discussion are clearly off-topic. There is no way for anyone to authoritatively answer this, since any answer will be prefaced with "It depends."

Comment: @RobertH: You don't need to edit your question to include the answer, that's what the answer fields are for. Just accept an answer if it helped you, which will tell everyone that this solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy: MySQL, as SQL Server Express can only work as a replication slave.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms151819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: If you don't need real-time (or close) replication for SQL Express but are just using it for DR, you can script a backup, remote copy, and remote restore pretty easily.